# How to run a loop of Google Doc IDs from Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to run a loop in an App Script, but the script stops when it goes through the loop the second time.

The Google Doc id is coming from a list in a Google Sheet.  I can get it to work without the loop, but as soon as the sheet range is updated, it does not look at the next id.  Can anyone see what has gone wrong?

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1LETEuEdYxyIxQtQgFWTwm3GgZWDAR5ehUUEIh_jN7zA');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lr = sheet.getRange(2,5).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow();

  for(var i=0; i<lr+1; i++) { 
    var id = sheet.getRange(i+2,5,1,1).getValue();
    var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var docInside = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody();
    var text = docInside.getTables();
    var table = text[3].getNumRows();
    var val = text[3].getRow(2).getText();
    var pasteArea = doc.editAsText();

    pasteArea.appendText(val);

    var text = docInside.getTables();
    var loops = text[7].getNumRows();

    for(var i=0; i<loops-5; j++) { 
      var val = text[7].getRow(j+5).getText();
      var pasteArea = doc.editAsText();

      pasteArea.appendText(val);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: There is no editAsText() in Document Class and this `var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();` doesn't need to be in the loop.  But the real problem is that you have one loop inside the other with the same index.  That's most likely your problem.

Comment: The way you're using `i` is ambiguous. Use a different variable like `j` in the nested loop

Comment: I have updated the script, so it now has different variables in the loops.  There is also an editAsText already in the script, but this is in the loops.  Should this be out of the loop?            I have tried the script again and received the error message "Action not allowed" that occurs at the row 10 - var docInside = DocumentApp.openById(id).getBody();  Any ideas?

Comment: You have `var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();` and you also have `var pasteArea = doc.editAsText();` but if you look at [Document Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document)  you will see that there is no method called editAsText() in this class.  Also you haven't updated the code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1LETEuEdYxyIxQtQgFWTwm3GgZWDAR5ehUUEIh_jN7zA');
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var lr=sh.getRange(2,5).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow();
  var vA=sh.getRange(2,5,lr-1,1).getValues();
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) { 
    var docid=DocumentApp.openById(vA[i][0]);
    var tA=docid.getBody().getTables();    
    doc.getBody().appendParagraph(tA[3].getRow(2).getText());
    var rows=tA[7].getNumRows();
    for(var j=0;j<rows-5;i++) { 
      doc.getBody().appendParagraph(tA[7].getRow(j+5).getText());
    }
  }
}
```